# Is there a default norm for the (finite) product of Normed Vector Spaces?

Tags: normed-spaces

I am trying to figure out what could be *the* norm associated with the product of two normed vector spaces.

I know we can define several norms on it, for example, if we have $(X, \|·\|)$ and $(Y, \|·\|)$ two normed vector spaces we can define the following norm on $X \times Y $ :

$$ \|(x, y)\|=(\|x\|^p+\|y\|^p)^{1/p}$$

So... Are all these norms equivalent in  $X \times Y $ ? Is there a standard norm that can be defined  $X \times Y $ ?

Note that $X$ and $ Y$ can be infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose a norm in $X \times Y$ as:
$$
    \|(x,y)\| = \varphi(\|x\|, \|y\|)
$$
where $\varphi$ is arbitrary norm in $\mathbb R^2$.

**UPDATE:** As noticed in comments, not every norm $\varphi$ generates a norm over $X \times Y$ this way. I think $\varphi$ should be monotonically increasing by both arguments in positive quarter. Various $L_p$ norms are OK, for instance.

---

Now consider two different norms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ in $\mathbb R^2$. They are obviously equivalent in $\mathbb R^2$, so there are some positive constants $m$ and $M$, such that (for $a \neq 0 \vee b \neq 0$):
$$
  m \le \frac{\varphi(a, b)}{\psi(a, b)} \le M
$$

Now this is obviously also true for the corresponding norms in $X \times Y$ (for $x \neq 0 \vee y \neq 0$):
$$
  m \le \frac{\varphi(\|x\|, \|y\|)}{\psi(\|x\|, \|y\|)} \le M
$$
Which means that they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my question.

Comment: As long as $\varphi(\|x\|, \|y\|)$ vanishes iff both $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ vanish, the topology such a norm induces is the product topology. Assuming it is indeed a norm of course.

Comment: @stgatilov, doesn't your answer have a flaw, since a counter-example is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275073/equivalence-of-norms-defined-on-a-cartesian-product by James Well stated after Jochen's answer ? Because given a norm $||.||_X$ (on $X$) and a norm $||.||_Y$ (on $Y$), then in general the function $||(.,.)||=\varphi(||.||_X,||.||_Y)$ corresponding to $\varphi$ need not be a norm on $X\times Y$ according to that example.

Comment: @serenus. You are right! I paid attention to the matter of equivalence, but did not thoroughly check that it is a norm. Updated the answer now.